# Check Something Every Time App Loaded

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to check something every time there is a new session in an iOS application.

Neither `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{` nor `-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{` are achieving what I want here.

What do you recommend to achieve what I want? I want to keep multitasking...

Comment: What do you define as a "session?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your object as an observer for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notfication (or related notifications) in order for it to perform some check whenever the app enters the foreground.  Using this code, you can associate the notification with a block:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                       addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification 
                                   object:nil 
                                    queue:nil 
                               usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {
                                  // Whatever check is needed
                               }];
```

You are not restricted to doing all that work in your app delegate.